# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() on GCP platform

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, onesignal

I want to send a push notification from my GCP server using PHP. I used the following function to achieve this. When I run the same script in my local Xampp Server it works fine. However when I deploy on the GCP server its is giving the error.

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in

Here is my code:

```
function sendMessage($appId,$userId){
    $content = array(
                     "en" => "Welcome ",
                     );

    $fields = array(
                    'app_id' => $appId,

                    'include_player_ids' => [$userId],

                    'contents' => $content,

                    ); 


    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init(); // Showing error here
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxx'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Is curl-php installed on the GCP server?

Comment: It seems that curl is not enabled in your php ini. Have a look there : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#dynamically_loadable_extensions

Comment: @Steven how to edit the php.ini in App Engine?

Comment: @anyber, Steven.. Thank you. I have installed php.ini and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Add next php code to check is curl enabled before $ch = curl_init();

```
// Script to test if the CURL extension is installed on this server

// Define function to test
function _is_curl_installed() {
    if  (in_array  ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Ouput text to user based on test
if (_is_curl_installed()) {
  echo "cURL is <span style=\"color:blue\">installed</span> on this server";
} else {
  echo "cURL is NOT <span style=\"color:red\">installed</span> on this server";
}
```